# Woocommerce variable product stock qty message

Tags: woocommerce, product, stock

Is there a way to change variable product default stock message?

My goal is to check how many items are in stock, if there is more than 20 items it should display "More than 20 available" and if it is under 20 items, it says exactly how much items are left (15 items left)

Is it doable?
I have googled the hell out of it but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
  if ( $_product->product_type == 'variation' && $_product->manage_stock == "yes" && $_product->stock > 20 ) $availability['availability'] = 'more than 20';
  return $availability;
}
```

Comment: This helped me alot! Have been searching for a similar problem for weeks without progress.. with some tweaks this was exactly the thing I needed!