# Woocommerce product custom displayed stock status based on stock quantity

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I want to show the actual stock quantity when the quantity is under 20 and a text like "more than 20" when the quantity is more han 20 for products with or without variations.
Also for products that only have the stock status set to "in stock" (without quantity) i want the text "more than 20" to show.
I have tried some different options but can't get it right.

In short what i need to achieve:
When stock is 20 or less: show actual stock
When stock is more than 20: show "more than 20"
When stockstatus is set to in stock: show "more than 20"

Would be happy for some advices here.

I tried to change the code below in different ways, as it is now, it just shows "more than 20" and "less than 20" and products that are just in stock without quantity get "out of stock" message:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_get_stock_html', function($html, $product) {
    $current_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    if ($current_stock <= 0) {
        $new_html = __('Out of stock', 'txtdomain');
    } else if ($current_stock > 20) {
        $new_html = sprintf('More than 20 %s', __('in stock', 'txtdomain'));
    } else if ($current_stock < 19) {
        $new_html = sprintf('Less than 20 %s', __('in stock', 'txtdomain'));
    } else {
        $new_html = __('In stock', 'txtdomain');
    }
    return sprintf('<p class="stock">%s</p>', $new_html);
}, 10, 2);
```

Also this topic seems to be very close to the solution, but it did not show any quantity when i tried: [Woocommerce variable product stock qty message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221558/woocommerce-variable-product-stock-qty-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following revisited code using `get_manage_stock()` method to solve your issue:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_get_stock_html', 'filter_wc_get_stock_html', 10, 2 );
function filter_wc_get_stock_html($html, $product) {
    $current_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    $manage_stock  = $product->get_manage_stock();
    $stock_status  = $product->get_stock_status();

    if ( $manage_stock ) {
        if ( $current_stock <= 0 ) {
        $new_html = __('Out of stock', 'txtdomain');
        } else if ($current_stock < 20) {
            $new_html = sprintf('Less than 20 %s', __('in stock', 'txtdomain'));
        } else if ($current_stock > 19) {
            $new_html = sprintf('Up to 20 %s', __('in stock', 'txtdomain'));
        }
    } else {
        if ( $stock_status === 'outofstock' ) {
            $new_html = __('Out of stock', 'txtdomain');
        } else {
            $new_html = __('In stock', 'txtdomain');
        }
    }
    return sprintf('<p class="stock">%s</p>', $new_html);
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Yes, It looks like it works with a small customization. There was a missing ; in the end of the first row in the code. Then i changed the "In stock" text to "more than 20" -so now it works perfect!  Many thanks!

Comment: @Åsa Oups! Yes, added.